# XCODE Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKLoginButton'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Сегодня обновил Cocoapods до версии 1.0.1 и получил сразу букет ошибок. Сначала компилятор никак не мог найти файлы .h, которые используются в PODах, в итоге поколдовав я поправил пути в Build Settings моего проекта и проблема исчезла, однако тут же появилась новая:

{PROJECT}/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKLoginButton'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего я пошел штурмовать google.com

нашел, что проблема может быть в Build Settings и поправил их

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

включал и убирал скрипт в podfile

```
    post_install do |installer|  
      installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|  
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'  
      end  
    end
```

откатывал версию cocoapods до старой

Но ничего из этого мне не помогло.

Что означает эта ошибка и каким образом можно ее решить?

Answer (score 1):

Поправил так:

В PODах было три FBSDK - CoreKit, LoginKit, ShareKit

Во ВСЕХ файлах, в которых возникала выше описанная ошибка, заменил импорты таким образом:

Если файл входит в фреймворк - то менял

```
#import <Module/Header.h>
```

на

```
#import "Header.h"
```

Eсли файл не входил в фреймворк

```
#import <Module/Header.h>
```

на

```
 @import Module;
```